# POST method to update XML file

Tags: python, xml, post, flask

I'm trying to use the following code to update a particular tag (`<a>`) text on file.xml

```
@app.route('/model', methods = ['POST'])
def api_post():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/xml':
        f = open("/home/file.xml", "w")
        f.write(request.data)
        f.close()
```

but the test with curl is not working...

```
curl -H "Content-type: text/xml" -X POST http://192.168.1.12:8080/model -d "<a>hello</a>"
```

Could someone help since I can't find any examples of flask and XML for the POST method?

Answer (score 0):

**Possibilities:**

1. You're routing `/data` POSTs to `api_post()`, but you're sending
   your curl test to `/model`.
2. HTTP header names are case-insensitive, but Python dictionary keys
   are not.  You're posting 'Content-type' but checking 'Content-Type'.

*Suggestion: Expand upon "not working..." by providing any error messages or log entries which do not make sense to you.  If there are no traces of trouble, add diagnostics until there are.*

Comment: sorry, I missed that. But the problem persists.

Comment: Ok.  I added a second possibility and a suggestion to expand upon what you mean by "not working."